# A callback or backgroud task to check if an app was downloaded?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I'm trying to build an app in which I want to check if some other app was installed on the phone not at a particular time but a background task that continuously checks if the app was downloaded ever after the install of my app. Or callback thats called every time any app is installed? something like applicationDidFinishInstalling. 
I have my doubts that there's gonna be anything like that but if anybody knows? or a hack to achieve this?
Any help will be greatly appreciated. TIA

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is no, you can’t achieve that(thankfully!). Read up upon sandbox and you will find out what you can and can’t access.